# How can I call an anonymous function from inside itself in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to re-run the function 'check' without calling check() in the else statement? Maybe call itself somehow?

If I have multiple instances of this function, they end up calling each other, unless I change it to check1, check2, etc.. While this is prob. a performance killer, I was just trying it out for a prototype app.

```
(function check () {
  if (typeof foo !='undefined') {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to load, trying again");
    setTimeout(function(){ check(); }, 10);
  }
})();
```

Comment: `they end up calling each other` Example please

Comment: Why would you have two functions named check? Maybe setInterval is what you want? You can do a clearInterval inside to stop iteration...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you *could* use `arguments.callee` to call it, but it's a bad idea, a performance hit, and it isn't valid in strict mode.

What you've quoted is valid JavaScript and *should not* make `check` call another `check` function if you have one alongside it. Sadly, though, [it will in IE8 and earlier](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) because they quite incorrectly leak the name `check` to the surrounding scope (named function *expressions* do not add the function name to the surrounding scope like function declarations do — except on IE8 and earlier [and that's not all they get wrong with them]).

So the solution is to use an anonymous function to hide a named one:

```
(function() {
    // A check function
    check();
    function check () {
      if (typeof foo !='undefined') {
        // do stuff
      } else {
        console.log("Failed to load, trying again");
        setTimeout(function(){ check(); }, 10);
      }
    }
})();
(function() {
    // A complete different one
    check();
    function check () {
      if (typeof foo !='undefined') {
        // do other stuff
      } else {
        console.log("Failed to load, trying again");
        setTimeout(function(){ check(); }, 10);
      }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Interesting, this ended up solving the re-calling problem... which I think might be related to some black magic with Meteor, as I couldn't re-create it in a static page. I hope meteor gets some kind of a module loader soon!

Comment: @SkinnyGeek1010: Interesting! Glad that helped.

Answer (score 3):

How about using an interval instead removing the need to call itself, as this will be done automatically until you clear the interval:

```
(function(){
   var interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(typeof foo != 'undefined'){
         clearInterval(interval);
         // do stuff
      }else{
         console.log("Failed to load, trying again");
      }
   },10)
})();
```

Comment: Shoot, I didn't see this until after I accepted the other one. This basically scopes the var interval and also keeps running repeatedly unless foo is defined. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this instead:

```
var inter;

function check() {
    if (typeof foo !== 'undefined') {
        clearInterval(inter);
        // do stuff
    } else {
        console.log("Failed to load, trying again");
    }
}
inter = setInterval(check, 10);
```

It's not a drop in replacement, but I think it's better style.